# Sonar using Sonar Runner on Jenkins Job fails to access classes

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Im trying to run a sonar analysis on a Jenkins Job. Im using ant so im using Sonar Runner and sonar.properties in the projects. Im configuring the the binaries to

sonar.binaries=build/ant/classes

After a successfull build Sonar starts and is running a while. But i get a lot of warnings during bytecode analysis.

Im getting WARN  XX - Class 'XX' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.

for every class...

I dont really know why classes are all there?

Answer (score 5):

These are warnings issued by Findbugs, which requires access to source, compile binaries and  3rd party libraries.

To resolve these warnings you need to include an additional **sonar.libraries** property, populated with the 3rd party jars your code depends upon (See [Analaysis Parameters documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters))

Comment: you mean for every class which is not accessible i need sonar.libraries? but isnt there another message like "The following classes where missing " which show the missing library classes? For me it looks like he can't access most of the classes he should analyze...

Comment: @Hannes I think there may actually be two findbugs error messages. I can't remember the detail. In any case the purpose of the "sonar.libraries" property is to correctly populate the java path used by findbugs. BTW it's worth nothing Sonar will use a property or an ANT path, just make sure its called "sonar.libraries". Using the Java runner makes this more difficult....

Comment: @Hannes Did you solve this issue? I'm having the same issue with maven and jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem, but that was because of an issue with the maven caches.

I had run mvn clean install in the directory on my local machine, but was running sonar on the directory on a virtual box.  This resulted in classes not being found.

Comment: Can you extend what you did to fix the problem? Run mvn clean on the sonar instance?

Comment: hopefully this helps you out @tholu2  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528033/sonarqube-class-not-found-during-main-ast-scan

Comment: Thanks, my problem was simple, had to add a pre-build step where I would do an `mvn compile`.