# Fixing 'Class is not accessible through the ClassLoader.' warning with Jenkins, SonarQube, and Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube

When SonarQube analyzes my Java project which is built using Gradle and Jenkins, I get a lot of warnings about third party libraries not being accessible through the ClassLoader:

```
WARN  - Class 'org/slf4j/Logger' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
WARN  - Class 'com/google/gson/Gson' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
```

These libraries are all listed as dependencies in my [build.gradle](http://pastebin.com/WmAJtApw).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913787/sonar-using-sonar-runner-on-jenkins-job-fails-to-access-classes#answer-13922977) about using the `sonar.libraries` property where I'd give a path to the Jar. But because Gradle downloads those dependencies for me, the paths look like this on my machine: `/home/siberut/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/6b262da268f8ad9eff941b25503a9198f0a0ac93/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`.

And those paths change with every new version of the library.

So how can I get I get rid of those warnings? Is there maybe a way to let Gradle tell SonarQube about the location of the Jars?

Thanks

Edit:
I'm using SonarQube Server 4.1.1, [Gradle Plugin 1.23](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin), [Sonar Plugin 2.1](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Jenkins+Plugin), Sonar Runner 2.3 and `gradle --version` gives:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_21 (Oracle Corporation 23.7-b01)
OS:           Linux 3.10-2-486 i386
```

Here is the complete console output of a build including all the warnings: [Link](http://pastebin.com/s4d5gMSc)

Jenkins calls [my build.gradle](http://pastebin.com/WmAJtApw) like this:
[image: Jenkins calls build.gradle]

Jenkins calls SonarQube like this:
[image: Jenkins calls SonarQube]

---

Edit: Just like Peter Niederwieser said, letting Gradle invoke SonarQube gets rid of the warnings. The relevant part of my configuration is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815072/get-link-to-sonar-dashboard-in-jenkins-when-calling-gradle-sonarrunner).

Comment: Which version of Gradle and Sonar? Which Gradle Sonar plugin?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: I added the versions of my plugins.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Gradle Plugin 1.23, Sonar Plugin 2.1, Sonar Runner 2.3`. Where do you get to choose these versions? I was merely asking if you are using Gradle's old `sonar` plugin or the new `sonar-runner` plugin. (You'll need the latter.) Or don't you use Gradle's built-in Sonar support at all?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: Sorry for not being clear enough. Those plugins are Jenkins plugins. Jenkins calls SonarQube, Gradle builds the project and invokes Jacoco. I added my `build.gradle` and two screenshots of my Jenkins build configuration in the latest edit. Thanks for your perseverance.

Comment: first run gradle compile goal and then run sonar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set `sonar.libraries`. But in order to set this property manually, you'll have to define a Gradle task that copies all external dependencies to a lib directory, and then use `sonar.libraries=path/to/lib/*.jar` to reference them. Instead, I'd invoke Sonar via the `sonar-runner` Gradle plugin, which will take care of setting the above properties (plus `sonar.libraries` and others) for you.

Comment: Thanks, invoking Sonar via `gradle sonarRunner` makes the warnings disappear. I have a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815072/get-link-to-sonar-dashboard-in-jenkins-when-calling-gradle-sonarrunner) if you don't mind.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Jenkins Sonar plugin, and I don't know if there is a solution. There should be a generic way to add links to the Jenkins project page, though.

Comment: @Peter When I run sonar-runner it complains about not being able to find class files for jacoco plugin that is included with SonarQube. When I explicitly set binaries property to the folder with class files it starts giving me the errors like in question. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: When using sonarRunner is it possible to add additional libraries that gradle didn't set, for example with Java 8 the JavaFX .class files from jfxrt.jar don't seem to get picked up automatically....

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed this issue for me in `build.gradle`

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        def compileDependencies = project.configurations.compile.files.collect {it.path}join(",")
        def compileOnlyDependencies = project.configurations.compileOnly.files.collect {it.path}join(",")

        property "sonar.java.libraries", "$compileDependencies,$compileOnlyDependencies"
        property "sonar.test.libraries", "$compileDependencies,$compileOnlyDependencies"

    }
}
```