# Copying class files to Sonar working directory

Tags: android, sonarqube, jacoco, sonar-runner

I am developing for Android and using SonarQube 4.5.2. My app uses Gradle 2.2.1 with Sonar runner 2.4, and Jacoco for code coverage.

I wish to copy class files to sonar working directory, which is build/sonar; and for this purpose I have created a task that copies the binaries to Sonar working directory. Once the files are copied I run the Sonar runner task.

Until last month this was working fine and I could see all the coverage related metrics on SonarQube. But now when the Sonar runner task starts it cleans the sonar working directory which removes all the binaries, resulting in Sonar not being able to find the class files and consequently giving me zero coverage.

I don't remember changing anything on both SonarQube server and in the Sonar runner task. Is there any property that can prevent Sonar runner from cleaning the existing working directory?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube working directory should not be used by anything else than SonarQube itself. If you need binaries for the analysis, you should put them elsewhere (like `"build/classes"`) and manage the cleanup by yourself in your Gradle script.

Comment: I already have my binaries in `"build/intermediates/classes/"` by default (I am doing Android development with Gradle). Apparently SonarQube looks for binaries in `{sonar-working-directory}/build/` and isn't able to find them after which it complains and doesn't run Jacoco analysis. Not sure how your solution would help. Is it that putting the binaries in `build/classes` would automatically make SonarQube detect the binaries?

Comment: SonarQube Java plugin uses the information provided by the user to know where the binaries are... Please read the documentation (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Java+Plugin) and more specifically the "sonar.binaries" property.

Comment: I use SonarRunner gradle plugin 2.4 and when I set `sonar.binaries` property to my class files I get Class not found Error
`16:13:55.480 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
16:13:55.835 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
16:13:55.838 INFO  - 374 source files to be analyzed
16:13:56.058 ERROR - Class not found: android.content.Context
16:13:56.058 ERROR - Class not found: android.content.SharedPreferences`
And so on.

Someone suggested I should set `sonar.libraries` property as well but then according to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21812920/1419349 SonarRunner should handle it all for me.