# SonarQube "Class Not Found" during Main AST Scan

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

My setup:

- Sonarqube 5.1.1
- Sonar-Maven Plugin 2.6 (also tried 2.7 and 3.6)
- JDK 1.7.0_51

Example of the error:

```
16:00:54 [INFO] [23:00:54.219] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
16:00:55 [INFO] [23:00:55.030] Java Main Files AST scan...
16:00:55 [INFO] [23:00:55.030] 1532 source files to be analyzed
16:00:58 [ERROR] [23:00:57.927] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
16:00:58 [ERROR] [23:00:57.928] Class not found: javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
16:00:58 [ERROR] [23:00:58.114] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
```

According to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589302/where-is-javax-annotation), javax.annotation should be part of java 1.7 and up.  Furthermore, I've tried putting it in the local maven repository but that didnt help.

So where is Sonar trying to find this package?  Any help?!?

**Update:**

- I've tried modifying the sonar-maven-plugin to include a dependency on javax.annotation
- I've tried putting the dependency in my maven's settings.xml
- Upgrading my JDK to 1.8 has not helped.

Comment: Can you check if the javax.annotation*.jar is present in your Java installation? `<java-install-dir>\lib\missioncontrol\plugins` Also curious if you have JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH variables set?

Comment: This class should be picked in the JDK running the analysis. So please double check the jdk running the analysis as suggested by @Techtwaddle

Comment: Ah thank you @Techtwaddle.  It's missing from my java installation. Thank you so much!  I'd been searching on and off for days without much luck

Comment: Hmm...so I was pretty sure it had worked, but it turns out I had only glanced at a part where there weren't any instances of the class not found error.  

The bug is still there.  Any help?

Comment: @Techtwaddle do you think Sonar uses the JDK's lib plugins to scan the java files or since i'm running this via maven, does it check the maven repository ?

Comment: Still stuck on this!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/annotation/package-summary.html the classes you expect are not part of JDK 7.

The classes you're looking for are part of google JSR-305 implementation that was initiated here https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nullable.java?r=24 and which moved to Findbugs:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

According to https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305 the JSR-305 is finished, but is in *dormant* status and has not been added to a JDK release yet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Reading this answer, I'm not sure what is the solution.  Should I add this dependency withing the sonar maven plugin configuration ?

Comment: I see similar problems and adding the google findbugs dependency to the project dependencies helps. Similar problems occured with joda convert like `[ERROR] [20:44:25.247] Class not found: org.joda.convert.ToString`. Hence I added

Answer (score 9):

To avoid adding SonarQube specific dependencies to your project, define a profile like this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonarqube</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

Then run your sonar analysis with a command like

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar -Psonarqube,sonarqube-dev
```

The sonarqube-dev profile is defined in my ~/.m2/settings.xml and it just specifies where my development environment SonarQube installation is

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonarqube-dev</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- no direct db connections in new sonar -->
            <sonar.host.url>
                http://localhost:9000/
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

What is achieved by all  this?

- sonarqube analysis specific dependencies don't pollute the project unnecessarily
- no sonarqube maven plugin defined in pom.xml. Each developer and Jenkins can use whatever sonar plugin and server installation they wish

Comment: Why do you include the Joda dependency?

Comment: [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</id>\n        <dependencies>... @278:23)  @ /home/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml, line 278, column 23

Comment: Could you be more specific where to add the first profile? If I change the sonar profile in ~/.m2/settings.xml, I get warnings like that of rhinoceros.xn... I think you mean [Different dependencies for different build profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166895/different-dependencies-for-different-build-profiles)

Answer (score 2):

This is more an addendum to the latest answer:

I see similar problems and adding the google findbugs dependency to the project dependencies helps. Similar problems occured with joda convert like

`[ERROR] [20:44:25.247] Class not found: org.joda.convert.ToString`

Hence I also added

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>`
```

But note, that I set the scope to provided to prevent these new dependencies to be added to a resulting war file.

However, I still wonder why these errors occur since none of the analyzed classes seem to use these annotations?